# Improving Shell Script Performance

Tags: regex, performance, unix, shell, grep

This shell script is used to extract a line of data from `$2` if it contains the pattern `$line`.

`$line` is constructed using the regular expression `[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+` (a simple email match), form the lines in file `$1`.

```
#! /bin/sh

clear

for line in `cat "$1" | grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+"`
do
    echo `cat "$2" | grep -m 1 "\b$line\b"`
done
```

**File `$1`** has short lines of data (< 100 chars) and contains approx. 50k lines (approx. 1-1.5 MB).

**File `$2`** has slightly longer lines of text (> 80 to < 200) and has 2M+ lines (approx. 200MB).

The desktops this is running on has plenty of RAM (6 Gig) and Xenon processors with 2-4 cores.

Are there any quick fixes to increase performance as currently it takes 1-2 hours to completely run (and output to another file).

*NB: I'm open to all suggestions but we're not in the position to complexity re-write the whole system etc. In addition the data come from a third party and is prone to random formatting.*

Comment: The e-mail address pattern is not by a longshot anyway near correct. As someone has already noted, it lacks support for underscore, which is fairly common. It also lacks support for lots of other characters (lacking support for the plus sign being my favorite pet peeve as I use the plus sign in addresses very often). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_address#Validation for more on this, and also http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html for a slightly more complete regular expression for e-mail addresses.

Comment: Thanks Mikael, +1 for the info

Answer (score 7):

Quick suggestions:

1. Avoid the [useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) and change `cat X | grep Y` to `grep Y X`.
2. You can process the `grep` output as it is produced by piping it rather than using backticks. Using backticks requires the first `grep` to complete before you can start the second `grep`.

Thus:

```
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" "$1" | while read line; do
    grep -m 1 "\b$line\b" "$2"
done
```

Next step:

1. Don't process `$2` repeatedly. It's huge. You can save up all your patterns and then execute a single grep over the file.
2. Replace loop with `sed`.

No more repeated `grep`:

```
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" "$1" | sed -E 's/^|$/\\1/g' > patterns
grep -f patterns "$2"
```

Finally, using some `bash` fanciness (see `man bash` → Process Substitution) we can ditch the temporary file and do this in one long line:

```
grep -f <(grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" "$1" | sed -E 's/^|$/\\b/g') "$2"
```

---

That's great unless you have so many patterns `grep -f` runs out of memory and barfs. If that happens you'll need to run it in batches. Annoying, but doable:

```
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" "$1" | sed -E 's/^|$/\\1/g' > patterns

while [ -s patterns ]; do
    grep -f <(head -n 100 patterns) "$2"
    sed -e '1,100d' -i patterns
done
```

That'll process 100 patterns at a time. The more it can do at once the fewer passes it'll have to make over your 2nd file.

Comment: a little bit of performance improvement , would be to omit the use of while read loop entirely. This is because if say, 1000 email addresses are found, the script will call grep on file2 1000 times. 
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" file1 > temp
grep -f temp file2

Comment: Using your final solution grep gave a ***out of memory*** error.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is you are piping too many shell commands, as well as unnecessary use of cat.

one possible solution using just awk

```
awk 'FNR==NR{
    # get all email address from file1
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
        if ( $i ~ /[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+/){
            email[$i]
        }
    }
    next
}
{
 for(i in email) {
    if ($0 ~ i) {
        print 
    }
 }
}' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

If $1 is a file, don't use "cat | grep". Instead, pass the file directly to grep. Should look like

```
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" $1
```

Besides, you may want to adjust your regex. You should at least expect the underscore ("_") in an email address, so

```
grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+" $1
```

Comment: Don't think you can have _ in domain names. So /[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+/ would be best

Answer (score 2):

I would take the loop out, since greping a 2 million line file 50k times is probably pretty expensive ;)

To allow for you to take the loop out
First create a file of all your Email Addresses with your outer grep command.
Then use this as a pattern file to do your secondary grep by using grep -f

Answer (score 1):

As John Kugelman has already answered, process the `grep` output by piping it rather than using backticks. If you are using backticks the whole expression within the backticks will be run first, and then the outer expression will be run with the output from the backticks as arguments.

First of all, this will be a lot slower than necessary as piping would allow the two programs to run simultaneously (which is really good if they are both CPU intensive and you have multiple CPUs). However there is another very important aspect to this, the line

```
for line in `cat "$1" | grep -i -o -E "[A-Z0-9.-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+"`
```

may become to long for the shell to handle. Most shells (to my knowledge at least) limit the length of a command line, or at least the arguments to a command, and I think this could become a problem for the `for` loop too.